# Size of an "average" $\epsilon$-net on the unit sphere

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider constructing a set $S_\epsilon\subseteq S^{d-1}$ of points on the sphere $\{x\in\mathbb R^d \mid ||x||_2=1\}$, such that
$$
\mathbb E\left[\min_{y\in S_\epsilon}||x-y||_2^2\right]\le \epsilon,
$$

where $x$ is a random point on the sphere and the expectation is with respect to the choice of $x$.

> **How big must $S_\epsilon$ be?**

---

I'm looking for a lower bound, although an upper bound may be interesting as well.

---

The motivation for this problem comes from an attempt to prove a lower bound on the number of bits that are needed to send a real-valued vector $x\in\mathbb R^d$ such that the receiver can estimate $x$ to within an ($\ell_2$ squared) error of $\epsilon||x||_2^2$. The formulation requires a few extra steps (including Yao's Minimax principle), but this is the component I'm missing.

Comment: A sphere is the boundary of a ball, so a $d$ dimensional sphere is in $d+1$ dimensional space.  It would make more sense for your set to be in $S^d$

Comment: @RossMillikan - Thanks for the correction, I edited the question.

Comment: It will be helpful if you mention, very roughly, the motivation for knowing the answer to this question. This seems to be a question in stochastic geometry, so are you reading about the subject from a particular text or paper? Kindly answer my questions in the question post itself, these will make your post more attractive and complete. Thanks once again.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, will do, thanks, Teresa.

Comment: @RB You have my +1, thank you very much for the additional information.

Comment: Let me see how I can be of service to you. I believe that your problem is somewhat well studied, though I cannot be too sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

If $\epsilon$ is small so the number of points is large you can ignore the curvature and consider packing $d$ dimensional balls into $d$ dimensional space.  For dimensions up to $8$ the densest [lattice packings](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePacking.html) are known.  For higher dimensions the densest packing is unknown and is suspected to often be nonlattice.

You can compute the $d$ volume of the $d$ sphere, divide by the $d$ volume of a $d$ ball of diameter $\epsilon$ and multiply by the packing density to get an approximation to the number of points you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't follow. $\epsilon$ may or may not be small (how'd you define that?), and I couldn't understand how the ball packing implies a (lower?) bound on the number of points needed for $S_\epsilon$.

Comment: In the $d=2$ case you are covering a sphere with spots.  You are pretending the sphere is large enough compared to the spots to be considered a plane.  You compute how much area each spot accounts for and the total area of the sphere to get the number.  This is just taking that approach to an arbitrary dimension.

Comment: I think of the problem as covering the sphere with dots regardless of the dimension. Do you mean that we should divide the *surface area* of the sphere by the area of a 2D circle with radius $\epsilon$?  This seems to give a lower bound if we were to guarantee that the distance is at most $\epsilon$ for any point on the sphere, and not that the expected distance from a random point is small(?).

Comment: The dots have the same dimension as the sphere.  The sphere is a $d$ dimensional manifold, so it needs $d$ dimensional things to fill it up.  The change from dot spacing of $2 \epsilon$ to random distance from a dot being $\epsilon$ will introduce a multiplicative factor of order $1$, which I should have mentioned.  As $d$ gets large all the volume of the dots is near the perimeter, so the average distance from a point in the dot to the center is just about the radius.  You do have to worry about the distance from the points between the dot to the nearest center.